# Mail sending with NLog in .NET Core 1.0

Tags: asp.net, email, asp.net-core, smtp, nlog

I am using NLog library for logging errors and need to send mail for that. Its working with MVC but in netcoreapp1.1 its giving error.

I am using

```
<target name="test" xsi:type="Mail"
     smtpServer="smtp.gmail.com"
     smtpPort="587"
     smtpUsername="xxxxxxx"
     smtpPassword="xxxxx"
     enableSsl="false"
     from="xxxxx@gmail.com"
     to="xxxxx@gmail.com" />
```

and

```
<logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="test" />
```

Please suggest any way to send mail in "netcoreapp1.1"
Its because of "netcoreapp1.1" not supporting mail sending thing.

Comment: More on this exciting story can be found here: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/1614

Comment: @RolfKristensen Thanks for the reply, i had seen this link but not proper explanation that how i use Mailkit with nlogs?

Comment: Believe the issue is waiting for an ambitious developer to step in, and make a GitHub PullRequest that implements a new NLog Target that uses MailKit, instead of SmtpClient.

Comment: @rolf you comment should be the answer IMO.

Comment: @Julian The answer should comes from the ambitious developer, that posts a link to a Pull Request on Github :)

Answer (score 2):

I have created an additional package for this - the [NLog.MailKit package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.MailKit)

With your config it should work :)

Also add this to your config:

```
<extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.MailKit"/>
</extensions>
```

Currently not implemented:

- PickupDirectory
- NTLM auth

For implementation, see [GitHub](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.MailKit)